# For some function $f(x,y)$, what is the difference detween $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_y$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Tags: partial-derivative

I was under the impression that the idea of taking a partial derivative of some function $f(x,y)$ with, for example, respect to $x$ is where you take a deriviatve of the function with respect to the variable in question while holding the rest of the variables as constants.

My thermodynamaics proff introduced the following notation
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_y
$$
he verbally described it as

> The partial derivative of $f$, with respect to $x$, while holding $y$ constant.

and he kept enforcing the point that
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_y \neq \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$
but I really do not understand why this is. They fundamentally say, and accomplish, the exact same thing, do they not?

Comment: that verbal description is literally the definition of a partial derivative. I assume what he might have meant is something like $$\left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{y=y_0}$$

Comment: You can find this discussed in various posts. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282799/where-does-the-relative-sign-come-from-in-this-chain-rule-application/2282804#2282804) is one example. In the simple case of a function $f(x,y)$ of independent variables $x,y$, there is no difference from the usual notation. Henry's assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

in strict mathematical notation this is the definition for partial derivative

In thermodynamics however we need a method to remember what variables we use.

Physically any thermodynamic function $f(x,y)$ can be converted using Legendre transform to $f(u,v)$ so i guess what the prof. meant was something like this:

Take for example the the state function for internal energy:

$du=dq-pdv$

Now for an ideal gas:

$dq=C_vdT$

where $C_v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}$
and we need to remember that the process is with respect to constant volume.

but we can also look at the process for constant pressure:

$C_pdT$
where now the pressure variable is the second variable.

how is this done?

$dh=du+d(pv)$
this is the Legendre transform to enthalpy.

So now the $C_p=\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}$

Only now $p$ is held constant.

The notation is simply a mnemonic to remember our state variables and therefore not a mathematical statement.